# Loop through all instances of ng-form inside form for validations

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5lk0yJXqaVJLxMTGHBuE?p=preview).

I generate input elements dynamically when "+ Name" button is clicked, each inside ng-form.

How can I grab all the instances of ng-form for validating each individual ng-form? So that the "+ Name" button remains disabled if the fields are not valid or a new ng-form is created?

**Edit** *More details about the form structure*

There are other fields in the form which I removed for brevity reasons. It is basically a long form, something like

```
<form name="myForm">
     <input name="one" />
     .
     .
     <div ng-repeat....>
         <ng-form>
            <input name="schoolName" />
         </ng-form>
     </div>
    <button>+ Name</button>  <!-- I cannot check for myForm.$valid here-->
    <!-- since the person might not filled the rest of the below fields -->
     <!-- hence the need to grab "each" "ng-form" --> 
    <input name="some" />
    <input name="other" />        
</form>
```

Comment: The same way you disable the submit button?

Comment: @TheSharpieOne - I cannot do that, since there are more fields after the ng-form. I added more details to the q.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form say:

> In angular forms can be nested. This means that the outer form is
>   valid when all of the child forms are valid as well.

Therefore your main form will be valid only when all children forms will be valid.

2) if you want / need to have references to children FormControllers in main form you need to use custom directives.

I update your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vvz6VXJUj4lF0NR9gjjL

- script.js contains 2 directives: "mainForm" and "childForm" which show you how they can interact
- "Results" section in index.html show when "mainForm" become valid. And as you can see it confirms what Angular.js documentation says